# Getting the ID of clicked image with PHP and load it's info from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need help with loading specific info for the image that has been clicked. The info is stored into a MYSQL database.

1. I need to determin which image was clicked, and obtaining the images
   ID
2. Then fetch the information about that image from the database
3. And the echo out the information about the image

link to image of the database structure: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8xrifn64psmc9qh/AAA5j_eous8sBpg4WP0dgrmya?dl=0

Thanks! This is the line of code i use to load the images from the database.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM klubbar ORDER BY namn ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$res) {
   echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
   exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   echo '<div class="klubbar"><a href=""><img     src="'.$row['bild'].'"alt="'.$row['namn'].'"title="'.$row['namn'].'"/></a></div>';
}
```

Comment: just a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801948/load-info-from-mysql-database-when-a-linkimage-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
$sel_club = $_GET['klub'];
      $sql="SELECT * FROM klubbar ORDER BY namn ASC";
      $res = mysql_query($sql);
      if (!$res) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
      }

      if($sel_club)
      {
        $sqlC= "SELECT * FROM klubbar WHERE namn ='$sel_club'";
        $resC= mysql_query($sqlC);

        if($rowC = mysql_fetch_assoc($resC))
        {
          $id = $rowC['id'];
          $namn = $rowC['namn'];
          $bild = $rowC['bild'];
          $lank = $rowC['lank'];
          $alder = $rowC['alder'];
          $dresscode = $rowC['dresscode'];

          echo 'Klub: '.$namn.'<br>Webbsida: '.$lank.'<br>Åldersgräns: '.$alder.'+ <br> Dresskod: '.$dresscode;
          echo 
          '<form method="post" action="anmalan.php">
            <label name="namn">Namn:</label>
            <input type="text" name="namn" placeholder="Förnamn Efternamn"/><br>
            <label name="antalGuess">Antal gäster</label>
            <select>
              <option>+0</option>
              <option>+1</option>
              <option>+3</option>
              <option>+4</option>
              <option>+5</option>
              <option>+6</option>
            </select><br>
            <label name="mejl">E-post:</label>
            <input type="text" name="mejl" placeholder="example@ex.com"/><br>
            <label name="telefon">Mobilnr:</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefon" placeholder="07x xxx xx xx"/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" />
          </form>'; 
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        }

      }
      else
      {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $namn = $row['namn'];
          $bild = $row['bild'];
          $lank = $row['lank'];
          $alder = $row['alder'];
          $dresscode = $row['dresscode'];
          echo '<div class="klubbar" ><a href="?klub='.$namn.'" id="'.$id.'"><img src="'.$bild.'"alt="'.$namn.'"title="'.$namn.'"/></a></div>';
        }
      }
```